# How to get total number in Power BI matrix rows

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax

Here's a sample of raw data in the Power BI table.
[image]

I want to sum the numbers of Col D group by Col B and Col C and list them as an aggregate number in matrix rows. How can I get the desire layout like this? It seems easy but couldn't figure it out.
Thank you in advance[image]

Forgot to mention Col C has more quarters than the listed. So the sum would go with the slicers outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a calculated column to your table and use this in your row list in the matrix:

```
NewColumn = CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[COL D]) , ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[COL A],'Table'[COL B] ))
```

Comment: Thank you, but this formula won't apply with the quarter slicers. I forgot to mention at the beginning. If I add the Col C in the formula as NewColumn = CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[COL D]) , ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[COL A],'Table'[COL B],'Table'[COL C] )), the matrix will show in 4 rows with every quarter numbers, not in the same row as the total numbers.

Comment: That is why I don't have the COL C in my formula.  My formula works for the example you gave.  Put COL A, COL B and the new column in your rows of the matrix.  Put the COL C in the columns of your matrix and put the COL E in the values of the matrix.